# Поиск текста в двух столбцах

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Допустим, мы ищем слово «Привет» в Тексте новости и в комментариях, относящихся к этой новости.  Вот мой запрос такой:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_comments u
LEFT OUTER JOIN my_news d
 ON u.page_id = d.id
WHERE (d.name LIKE '%{$value}%
 OR u.text LIKE '%{$value}%')  {$userId}
GROUP by d.id;
```

Но слово «Привет» может быть в `d.name`, но не в `u.text`. Результат надо вывести, а условие `ON u.page_id = d.id` — мешает.

Надо мне выводить результат по параметрам, которые заданы для базы my_news,  нашли новость –> идем ищем комент, и наоборот, нашли комент — идем ищем новость.

Comment: 1. у вас в запросе непонятно что делает конструкция `{$userid}`. вероятно, похоже на опечатку. 2. насколько я понимаю, приведенный запрос как раз и вернёт нужные вам пары строк из двух таблиц.

Comment: вот я составил [пример](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f856/3) прямо так, как и у вас, только без `group`: выводит именно те сочетания строк, которые вам требуются. возможно, я вас неправильно понимаю?

Answer (score 1):

возможно, вам требуется `right join`. вот пример:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47d6f/8)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table n (id int, m text);
create table c (n int, m text);

insert into n values
  (1, "привет"),
  (2, "пока"),
  (3, "привет");

insert into c values
  (1, "привет"),
  (1, "пока"),
  (2, "привет"),
  (2, "пока");
```

**Query 1**:

```
select n.id, n.m, c.m
from c
right join n
  on n.id = c.n
where c.m like "%привет%"
  or n.m like "%привет%"
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/47d6f/8/0)**:

```
| id |      m |      m |
|----|--------|--------|
|  1 | привет | привет |
|  1 | привет |   пока |
|  2 |   пока | привет |
|  3 | привет | (null) |
```

Answer (score 0):

Не используйте `SELECT *`, это плохая практика. Указывайте поля явно, потому что потом другому человеку придется разбираться, какие поля на самом деле нужны, а какие - нет.

Не используйте `LIKE` для подобной задачи, это плохая практика, она приводит к замедлению. Используйте полнотекстовый поиск MyISAM с соответствующим индексом.

Псевдоним таблицы должен быть логичным ("news" - n, "comments" - c). Не ленитесь писать перед псевдонимом `AS`.

```
$sql = "
    SELECT n.id, n.name, c.id, c.text
    FROM my_news AS n
    LEFT JOIN my_comments AS c
      ON c.page_id = n.id
    WHERE MATCH (n.name, c.text)
      AGAINST ('+{$value}' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
    GROUP by n.id;
";
```

Результат не проверял - после того, как первые же мои ответы другим людям остались без благодарности, заморачиваться нет желания.

Comment: использовать like не есть плохая практика. главное использовать по месту. использование MyISAM тоже не всегда верно. надо оптимально подходить к проектированию.

Comment: @Вадим Разумеется, это зависит от цели использования. Но для задачи поиска, подобной этой - плохая. Полагаю, что БД в принципе на данный момент не очень хорошо справляются с поиском строки в текстах, что и привело к появлению Sphinx и т.д.

Comment: из личной практики применения поле like %что-то% and поле like %что-то1% и так от 1 до n раз поиск в 70 000 записей не имел ощутимой задержки...на sql.ru приводились примеры аналогичного поиска и среди нескольких миллионов...конечно если искать в полях text, blob надо применять что-то более подходящее...поэтому я против категоричных заявлений о чем либо.